# Expand only some tuple elements to variable list

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

Say I have the following code:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
parsed_url = urlparse(url)
scheme, netloc, path = parsed_url[0], parsed_url[1], parsed_url[2]
```

Is there a more elegant or short way of assigning those three variables? It looks a bit messy to write `parsed_url` three times (I am expecting something other than renaming `parsed_url` to something shorter).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cut the tuple in half:

```
scheme, netloc, path = parsed_url[:3]
```

Or, to make it explicit that there are six values and you're ignoring three of them, you could assign to a dummy variable named `_`:

```
scheme, netloc, path, _, _, _ = parsed_url
```

Comment: An elegant solution, it's great!

Answer (score 2):

`parsed_url[:3]` will create a subtuple consisting of exactly the wanted parts.

So

```
scheme, netloc, path = parsed_url[:3]
```

will do what you need.